# find duplicate words in two files

Tags: python, file, duplicates

I've two text files. I need to check for duplicate words inside them. Is there a way more concise than this code?

```
file1 = set(line.strip() for line in open('/home/user1/file1.txt'))
file2 = set(line.strip() for line in open('/home/user1/file2.txt'))

for line in file1 & file2:
    if line:
        print(line)
```

Comment: What language are the files written in? And what is your definition of a word?

Comment: Duplicate words or lines?

Comment: Do these files contain one word in one line?

Comment: duplicate the words, thanks :)

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concise I am quite sure it is impossible to give less detail than what you have written here. Even though the code can be written even more compact

Comment: Why do you think your current code is not concise enough? Try writing the same in Java.

Comment: you should do `line.strip().split()` for checking duplicate words

Comment: You can always put a `;` and make it a one-liner, but what's the point? This is on the brink of not readable but yet compact.. Not sure what you want us to do except make your code actually non-readable. Also I'm not even sure `for line in file1 & file2` will give you the desired result unless the words happen to be on the exact same row, if two words were to be in both files but on different row numbers your code won't detect it, or will it?

Comment: Can you give us an example of your input and the expect output?

Answer (score 2):

You can write concise code but more importantly you don't need to create two sets, you can use `set.intersection` which will allow your code to work for larger data sets and  run faster:

```
with open('/home/user1/file1.txt') as f1,  open('/home/user1/file2.txt') as f2:
    for line in set(map(str.rstrip,f2)).intersection(map(str.rstrip,f2))):
        print(line)
```

For python2 use `itertools.imap`:

```
from itertools import imap
with open('/home/user1/file1.txt') as f1,  open('/home/user1/file2.txt') as f2:
    for line in set(imap(str.rstrip,f2)).intersection(imap(str.rstrip(f2))):
        print(line)
```

You create a single set  which is then added to iterating over the iterable passed in i.e the str.rstripped  lines of file2 as oopposed to creating two full sets of lines first then doing the intersection.

Answer (score 0):

This is one line shorter and closes both files after use:

```
with open('/home/user1/file1.txt') as file1, open('/home/user1/file2.txt') as file2:
    for line in set(line.strip() for line in file1) & set(line.strip() for line in file2):
        if line: 
            print(line)
```

Variation with only one set:

```
with open('/home/user1/file1.txt') as file1, open('/home/user1/file2.txt') as file2:
    for line in set(line.strip() for line in file1).intersection(line.strip() for line in 
                                                                 file2):
        if line: 
            print(line)
```

Comment: You can put all of that into a single line, but what's the point? We are not doing code golf on this site.

Comment: Well, it is still readable and it improves on the original approach by using the `with` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Even shorter:

```
with open('/home/user/file1.txt') as file1, open('/home/user/file2.txt') as file2:
    print "".join([word+"\n" for word in set(file1.read().split()) & set(file2.read().split())])
```