# How to find words inside two text files

Tags: python, string

First part of the script is OK (its removes `http://` and `www.`). Later I need to check if the words inside source are presents in exists.

```
source = open('/net/sign/temp/python_tmp/script1/source.txt','r')
exists = open('/net/sign/temp/python_tmp/script1/exists.txt','r')

with source as f:
        lines = f.read()
        lines = lines.replace('http://','')
        lines = lines.replace('www.','')

        for a in open('/net/sign/temp/python_tmp/script1/exists.txt'):
            if a == lines:
                print("ok")
```

The content of `source.txt`:

```
www.yahoo.it
www.yahoo.com
www.google.com
http://www.libero.it
```

---

The content of `exists.txt`:

```
www.yahoo.com
```

Comment: It's not clear at all what you are trying to do. Do you need to find all words which exist in both files? What's your definition of a word? What about case sensitivity? Also I don't think `read` is doing what you are expecting it to do, otherwise you would not have called the return value `lines`.

Comment: why you `open` `exists.txt` file twice?

Comment: First of all, you have to extract words to some data structures (sets will be perfect, I believe). Currently you manipulate only lines. Then you have to compare these sets if they intersect. Is it clear to you how to do it?

Comment: Can you provide some sample contents for ```source.txt``` and ```exists.txt``` files?

Comment: `if ("http://" and "www.") in a:` ?

Comment: @IgorPomaranskiy: yes, I 've to compare both files.

Comment: An efficient way to compare to files http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588974/find-duplicate-words-in-two-files/34592626#34592626

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
source_words = set()
with open('source.txt') as source:
    for word in source.readlines():
        source_words.add(word.replace('http://','').replace('www.','').strip())

exist_words = set()
with open('exist.txt') as exist:
    for word in exist.readlines():
        exist_words.add(word.replace('http://','').replace('www.','').strip())

print("There {} words from 'source.txt' in 'exists.txt'".format(
   "are" if exist_words.intersection(source_words) else "aren't"
))
```

If you need to get exact words which are present in both files, they are in the intersection result:

```
print("These words are in both files:")
for word in exist_words.intersection(source_words):
    print(word)
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, judging from your example files what you are actually trying to do is find the lines which both text files share. If your files are not gigantic, a simple solution would be to read in the files and compute the intersection of their sets of lines.

```
>>> with open('source.txt') as s, open('exists.txt') as e:
...     result = set(s).intersection(e)
... 
>>> result
set(['www.yahoo.com\n'])
```

You can replace `'http://'` and `'www.'` afterwards with

```
result = [x.replace('http://', '').replace('www.', '') for x in result]
```

if you want to.

Comment: Didn't know you could open using `with` for multiple files. Nice answer. :)

Comment: @erip it only becomes a little tricky for an unknown number of files :)

Comment: You are creating a set and  two lists for no reason http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588974/find-duplicate-words-in-two-files/34592626#34592626